# PHP Multidimensional Array Not Showing Values

Tags: php, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

I've search up and down but can't seem to get this array to function properly, I'm missing something simple but unable to figure out what exactly.

```
<?php

    $dates2 = 'Aug 30, 2013';
    $dates3 = 'Sep 13, 2013';

    $cards[0] = array(
        'card' => 'Discover',
        'pay'  => '875', 
        'when' => array('
            'Sep 03, 2013', 
            'Oct 03, 2013', 
            'Nov 03, 2013',
            'Dec 03, 2013'
        ),                    
    );
    $cards[1] = array(
        'card' => 'Visa',
        'pay'  => '375', 
        'when' => array(
            'Sep 23, 2013', 
            'Oct 23, 2013', 
            'Nov 23, 2013',
            'Dec 23, 2013'
        ),        
    );
    $cards[2] = array(
        'card' => 'Mastercard',
        'pay'  => '1025', 
        'when' => array(
            'Sep 12, 2013', 
            'Oct 13, 2013', 
            'Nov 13, 2013',
            'Dec 13, 2013'
        ),
    );
    $cards[3] = array(
        'card' => 'Amex',
        'pay'  => '650', 
        'when' => array(
            'Aug 25, 2013', 
            'Sep 05, 2013', 
            'Oct 25, 2013',
            'Nov 25, 2013'
        ),
    );

    for ($i=0; $i<=3; $i++){  
        if ($cards[$i]['when'][$i] > $dates2 && ($cards[$i]['when'][$i] < $dates3) or ($cards[$i]['when'][$i] == $dates2)) {
            print "<tr>
                <td>$cards[$i]['card']</td>
                <td><input class='amount' size='3' value='$cards[$i]['pay']'></td>
            </tr>";                                  
         } 
     }

?>
```

Output: Array['card'] Array['card'] Array['card'] Array['card']

Comment: Curious as to why it got a down vote? If you're going to downvote someone, you should provide feedback as to why.

Answer (score 1):

It's your output statement, this fixed it for me:

```
print "<tr><td>" . $cards[$i]['card'] . "</td><td><input class='amount' size='3' value='" . $cards[$i]['pay'] . "'></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference: [Variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> **Variable parsing**
>
> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables
>   are parsed within it.
>
> There are two types of syntax: a simple one and a complex one. The
>   simple syntax is the most common and convenient. It provides a way to
>   embed a variable, an array value, or an object property in a string
>   with a minimum of effort.
>
> The complex syntax can be recognised by the curly braces surrounding
>   the expression.

**Update:**

Please read on "Simple Syntax" and especially on "Complex Syntax" for this particular case.

```
print "<tr>
           <td>{$cards[$i]['card']}</td>
           <td><input class='amount' size='3' value='{$cards[$i]['pay']}'></td>
       </tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the variables or reset them then print them.

DEMO PHPfiddle http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ia5-dh6

This is with them reset

DEMO PHPfiddle http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7if-nd3

*note i have added the missing table tags too*

```
$CardType = $cards[$i]['card'];
$Payment = $cards[$i]['pay'];

print "<tr>
         <td>$CardType</td>
         <td><input class='amount' size='3' value='$Payment'></td>
       </tr>";
```